# c# - object reference not set to an instance of an object - LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a view where a user can see bookings they have made. I have a model that holds a list of 2 different kinds of bookings in different facilities, a hall and a room. So the model holds a list of hall bookings and a list of room bookings. In my controller, i'm trying to add all the hall bookings to the hall bookings list, and the same for the room bookings. But I am getting this error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is my model:

```
public class AllBookingsViewModel
{

    public List<HallActivityBooking> HallBookingsList { get; set; }

    public List<RoomBooking> RoomBookingsList { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class BookingsController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Bookings
    public ActionResult Bookings()
    {

        //Get current user
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var currentUser = db.Users.Find(userId);

        AllBookingsViewModel model = new AllBookingsViewModel();

        //Fill activity booking
        foreach (HallActivityBooking hallBooking in db.HallBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id))
        {
            model.HallBookingsList.Add(hallBooking); //<< This is where I get an exception
        }


        //Fill room bookings list
        foreach (RoomBooking roomBooking in db.RoomBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id))
        {
            model.RoomBookingsList.Add(roomBooking);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Here's what I tried (these are no longer still in my code):

I've tried declaring the model like:

```
var model = new AllBookingsViewModel
```

I've tried adding "FirstOrDefault" to the linq statement:

```
foreach (HallActivityBooking hallBooking in db.HallBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id).FirstOrDefault())
{
    model.HallBookingsList.Add(hallBooking);
}
```

This gives me this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0446  Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you
>   intend to invoke the 'method group'? ...  26  Active

Help would be appreciated

---

## **SOLVED**

Here is what I did to solve this problem:

The for-each was not necessary, I just needed to initialize the view model by giving it the value's of the LINQ statement:

```
        AllBookingsViewModel model = new AllBookingsViewModel();
        {
            model.HallBookingsList = db.HallBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id);
            model.RoomBookingsList = db.RoomBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id);
        };
```

Comment: Does each `HallBookings` record has a `CustomerUser` associated with it? From the error message you mentioned, null reference exception, I could assume that at least one `HallBookings` has as a `CustomerUser` a a null reference.

Comment: FirstOrDefault returns only one object matching the criteria of Where clause. So you can't use foreach on it. Which line of code gives null reference error?

Comment: Collections in `AllBookingsViewModel` are not initialized.

Comment: Yes, a HallBooking has a CustomerUser, at this point there is only 1 booking and it does not have a null CustomerUser referance. How would I go about initialising AllBookingsViewModel? it's not suppose to have anything in it unless there is a booking, if I initialise it won't that then just show the initialised booking in the bookings view? It should only show a booking if it exists.

Comment: yes, I figured as much using FirstOrDefault(), it was just something I tried but I removed it.

Comment: u can initialize it in the view model constructor to the default values

Comment: It seems that one of the objects manipulated in the action method is null, try to use the VS Debugger to figure out which one is it.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ab4z9u7Q_I

Comment: I should add, the line I get the error is:

                model.HallBookingsList.Add(hallBooking);

Comment: I did debug, and it seems the AllBookingsViewModel is null. I will try to initialise it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize properties

```
AllBookingsViewModel model = new AllBookingsViewModel();
model.HallBookingsList = new List<HallActivityBooking>();
model.RoomBookingsList = new List<RoomBooking>();  
//Your existing code
```

Or, You can use directly use LINQ result to set these properties.

```
AllBookingsViewModel model = new AllBookingsViewModel();
model.HallBookingsList = db.HallBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id);
model.RoomBookingsList = db.RoomBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id);
```

Comment: Yea, I needed to initialise it basically. Basically the foreach was unnecessary, here is what I did:

            AllBookingsViewModel model = new AllBookingsViewModel();
            {
                model.HallBookingsList = db.HallBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id);
                model.RoomBookingsList = db.RoomBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id);
            };

Problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What i think that's occuring here is that you may have one of your either `HallBookings` or `RoomBookings` with a `CustomerUser` in null.

So, when LINQ is executing your `Func` passed in the Where clause, one of your entities with CustomerUser in null, causes the error.

I don't know if your business logic permits that, but you can provide some null checks in the Func provided in the Where to avoid those null references.

Example:

```
//Fill activity booking
foreach (HallActivityBooking hallBooking in db.HallBookings.Where(x => x.CustomerUser != null ? x.CustomerUser.Id == currentUser.Id : false))
{
    model.HallBookingsList.Add(hallBooking);
}
```